# Understanding C program in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to understand this simple C program:

```
int square(int num) {
    return num * num; 
}
```

When it's in Assembly code:

```
square(int): 
  push rbp ;push rbp register onto stack
  mov rbp, rsp ;move contents of rbp register into rsp register 
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi ;not sure what happens here 
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4] ;not sure what happens here
  imul eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4] ;multiply eax and DWORD PTR [rbp-4] (?)
  pop rbp ;pop original register out of stack
  ret ;return
```

1. What is happening in the 3rd and 4th line?
2. Why did two more register (edi and eax) have to be used instead of rsp?
3. What is actually happening with DWORD PTR [rbp-4]?

Comment: Might I suggest you compile with optimizations on.

Comment: You forgot to enable optimizations hence all the extra stuff. It's just going through memory using a temporary variable at `[rbp-4]` With optimizations enabled that should reduce to `mov eax, edi; imul eax, eax; ret`.

Comment: I think it's allocating stack space for the result

Comment: Your analysis of line two is wrong. In Intel Assembly syntax the first operand is the destination, the second one is the source

Comment: This is unoptimized code where the argument _num_ in `edi` register is stored as local variable in the stack frame and copied back to `eax` register.

Comment: @stackptr : It isn't allocating stack space. I'd venture to guess from the output he's generating 64-bit Linux where there is a 128 byte red zone that can used since this is a leaf function. Allocating space for temporaries that can fit in the red zone doesn't require any adjustment to RSP

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/juws2k and experiment there

Comment: `mov rbp, rsp` means moving the content of rsp into rbp, not reverse

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi ;not sure what happens here
> ```

The x86_64 System V ABI passes function arguments via registers - the first integer argument is passed in the `rdi/edi` register.  So this line copies the argument `num` to a local (offset -4 bytes from the frame pointer value stored in `rbp`).

> ```
> mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4] ;not sure what happens here
> ```

This copies the value in the local to the `eax` register.

> ```
> imul eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4] ;multiply eax and DWORD PTR [rbp-4] (?)
> ```

And this multiplies the value in `eax` by the local, and stores the result to `eax` (which also happens to be the register in which the function return value is stored).

As others pointed out in the comments, compiling with optimization would likely eliminate the local, and write directly from `edi` to `eax`.